# Spring Boot with Liferay

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, liferay

I'm playing with Spring Boot developing portlets to Liferay portal. I was able to create a portlet with a vanilla Spring setup (without Spring Boot), the project is available in https://github.com/tmoreira2020/spring-boot-liferay-portlet. When I [add Spring Boot setup](https://github.com/tmoreira2020/spring-boot-liferay-portlet/commit/ac9f543eb5e022a793189b8f09a80f4a78094289) it stops to work. Basically what happens is that the user gets a blank page after the invocation of a action phase. Looks like that I'm missing something but what? Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution on this documentation [Deploying a WAR in an Old (Servlet 2.5) Container](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-servlet-2-5) from Spring.
The solution is implemented on commit [36c0f68](https://github.com/tmoreira2020/spring-boot-liferay-portlet/commit/36c0f6845d17fdd4dafc188049bb5b16bb8cbf3d).